# How do I include the Leap-Motion-Plugin in UE4 into an existing project?

Tags: plugins, leap-motion, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a project in UE4.7.5 and I want to use Leap Motion in the project. I downloaded the plugin and copied the LeapMotionController-folder into the plugin-folder of my existing project. I could now enable the plugin in the projectsettings. UE4 wanted to restart to use the plugin so I tried it. But then the message "The following modules are missing or built with a different engine version: UE4Editor-LeapMotionController.dll Would you like to rebuild them now?" appeared. So I pressed Yes. And now the error-message "MyProject could not be compiled. Try rebuilding from source manually" appeared. I don't know what to do now to make Leap Motion work. I can't find the missing module anywhere on my computer. And I don't know how to rebuild from the source manually.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: look at the title :)

Comment: are you following this: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/unreal/index.html?  If not ' I downloaded the plugin and copied the LeapMotionController-folder into the plugin-folder of my existing project' => downloaded for where?

Comment: thx for trying to help me :)
I followed these instructions but I left out the part where you have to build the 4.7 branch of engine from source because I already have the engine fully build.

Comment: I downloaded it at their official site at GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning the UnrealEngine 4.7 source version that already includes the plugin, building that, then opening your project with that should work. I don't think the binary version can be used with the plugin code.

Comment: Thank you! It did work.
But now the project doesn't recognize the leap motion device anymore.

Comment: Make sure the plugin is enabled (in the Unreal Editor plugin window).

Comment: I enabled it but now I don't really know which settings I have to set to use the Leap Motion device.
I can't find the device under Player Controller Class.
Do I need to create another GameMode? Or do I need a special character other than the DefaultCharacter in Default Pawn Class?

Comment: See https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/unreal/unreal/Leap_Unreal_Using_Plugin.html You can add the LeapMotionControllerComponent to an existing character controller and then the hands will be positioned relative to that character.

Comment: Ha! Thank you very much! I don't know why I didn't find this before.
I tried to use Leap Motion the same way as in the unofficial plugin but that's completely different.
Now I can finally start to work :)